# Which method is called when I press back key on my phone?

Tags: android

I have an app that has a lot of activities, all created with `ONACTIVITYRESULT`.

Which method is called when I press back key?

I need to know it because I have to `override/implement` code on it.

Comment: Doesn't it call the previous activity you were on? I found some code somewhere where you can override the back button, will have a look for it.

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea. What if the user presses the HOME key? Or holds down the HOME key? Or goes to a different activity using the notification? Or accepts a phone call?

Comment: With the code in my answer it only overrides the back button.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The method that is called for is: `onKeyDown` of your current `Activity`.

You can use this to **target** all Android versions:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
      if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
          return true;
      }

   return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

If you're targeting *newer* Android devices, the API for `Android 2.0` and above has made things a little easier:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try this. I have this code on the page after checking for the licence. If my user presses back, I do not want them to go onto the licence check page again so I just quit the app. You don't have to quit the app, you can call whatever you want in here...

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    // Quit if back is pressed     
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
    {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```